# Margin works normally when inline but doesn't work in css rules

Tags: html, css, jsf-2, margin

When I write something like:

```
<table style="margin-left: 30px;" >
</table>
```

or:

```
<div style="margin-left: 30px;">
            <h:commandButton value="add" action="a"></h:commandButton>
            <h:commandButton value="cancel" action="b" immediate="true"></h:commandButton>
</div>
```

The margin shows up properly.

But when I write:

```
<table class="marg" >
</table>
```

or:

```
<div class="marg">
    <h:commandButton value="add" action="a"></h:commandButton>
    <h:commandButton value="cancel" action="b" immediate="true"></h:commandButton>
</div>
```

With this rule:

```
.marg {
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-top: 30px; 
}
```

HTML generated code:

```
<table class="marg">
</table>
<div class="marg">
<input id="j_id1109917403_4227fec1:j_id1109917403_4227feb3" type="submit" value="add" name="j_id1109917403_4227fec1:j_id1109917403_4227feb3">
<input id="j_id1109917403_4227fec1:j_id1109917403_4227feae" type="submit" value="cancel" name="j_id1109917403_4227fec1:j_id1109917403_4227feae">
</div>
```

The table and button display without margin. Why ?

Comment: Please post code (HTML and CSS - as delivered to browsers) that demonstrates the issue. The code posted so far does not do that. Whatever the cause is, it is in some part of the code that was not disclosed. We cannot even see how the CSS rule is linked to HTML, if at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, please sorry, it was my very stupid mistake. I forget to add in HTML :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/myCSS.css"   media="all" />
```

I thought that I added it.

Comment: is this a answer or just additional data to question?

Comment: @SrinivasR: This is an answer.

Answer (score 1):

1. Test if the CSS rule is applied by adding a `background-color`:

   ```
   .marg {
     margin-left: 50px;
     margin-top: 30px;
     background-color: pink;
   }
   ```
2. If yes, then add `!important` to your existing instruction for testing purpose:

   ```
   .marg {
     margin-left: 50px !important;
     margin-top: 30px !important;
     background-color: pink;
   }
   ```

   1. Look in Firebug/Inspector which rules are applied; if there are many declarations, which one has an !important modifier or has more specificity than others or comes last and is finally applied.

Is your CSS applied? Does `!important` change something? What do you see in Firebug? Come back with a fiddle (without CSS reset!) if you still have a problem: HTML and CSS code can help us to understand your problem; back-end code that generates HTML doesn't

Comment: Thanks, for the answer. I add background color, but nothing changed. CSS doesn't applied. I refreshed browser(mozilla ctrl-f5) nothing changed. But when I look in firebug, in css class margin properly is shown.

Comment: Does your CSS file show into the CSS pane of Firebug? When editing it in CSS panel of Firebug, do you see the last modification you did with your IDE/text editor? Any proxy?

Answer (score -1):

The .marg css class has margin-left set to 50px unlike inside the attributes which is set to 30px.

Comment: I know, it's no matter, it is for testing, whatever no margin is applied.